# Malfunction of java native library in different scenarios

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native

My application wants to communicate with arduino through serial port using java native library (for reference: jSSC-2.8.dll).
I have the following problem: When I specify the location of the library as a JRE argument `-Djava.library.path="C:/native"` and run the program, everything works fine both through my IDE and when running the compiled jar through cmd, specifying that argument. When, however (having library loaded at runtime), I run the jar by double-clicking, the whole JVM crashes and writes a crash file containing

> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)

I also tried to load the native dll at runtime using `System.load("C:/native/jSSC-2.8.dll");`and run the application through the IDE and it worked fine. 
The only solution to run the jar by double-clicking was, by trial, running it with **administrator permissions**. Then the application worked fine.

But it makes little sense to me. I was expecting the native file run just the same as it did through the IDE. Why just running it through a jar-launched application without administrator permissions generated this fatal error inside the JVM, while in IDE it did not (As far as I know the IDE does not need any special permissions.)?

Error with low-level information: https://pastebin.com/nqsT6Nkx

Comment: You need to copy/paste the entire error message (format as code) to start with so we can see where the access violation occurred.

Comment: It might be you have different PATH settings for your IDE and regular system settings. In that case, you may run into situation where some dlls are visible in IDE while are not available (or are available in different version) in your regular user account. Make sure that all libs jSSC-2.8.dll depends on are present when you click your jar file.

Comment: It is not so, because the application has no problem running standalone while specifying the java library path to CMD. It looks like that when you specify a path to the JVM before the program runs, the JVM initiates dll properly. But at runtime, it initiates it through a system or whatever and it alters the permissions.